# Manipulating csv spreadsheet using R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, spreadsheet, import-from-csv

I want to write a basic loop that looks like this:

1. Import spreadsheet as data frame
2. scanning by Variable in header find missing data point "NA" remove all data for that calendar month for that variable, i.e.:

   Here var 'X' has 'NA' at the second january. I want to remove all january values of 'X'

   > ```
   >   X Y Z
   > ```
   >
   > jan  3  3  3
   >
   > jan NA  4  5
   >
   > jan  2  6  2
   >
   > feb  1  8 NA
   >
   > feb  4  2  3
   >
   > feb  9  4  1
   >
   > mar  5  NA 5
   >
   > mar  8  7  4
   >
   > mar  9  7  5

   Creating new dataframes that looks like:

   > ```
   >   X
   > ```
   >
   > feb  1
   >
   > feb  4
   >
   > feb  9
   >
   > mar  5
   >
   > mar  8
   >
   > mar  9
   >
   > ```
   >    Y
   > ```
   >
   > jan    3
   >
   > jan   4
   >
   > jan   6
   >
   > feb   8
   >
   > feb   2
   >
   > feb   4
   >
   > ```
   >   Z
   > ```
   >
   > jan  3
   >
   > jan  5
   >
   > jan  2
   >
   > mar  5
   >
   > mar  4
   >
   > mar  5
3. Save remaining 'complete months' (in this case 'X'feb-mar, 'Y' jan-feb, 'Z' jan&mar) in new data frame to export as new  .csv file

Any help getting started would be huge. If this has already been asked please direct me to the source I wasn't sure exactly how search for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ddf2 = ddf[,c(1,2)]
xdf = ddf[ddf$month!=ddf2$month[is.na(ddf2$X)], c(1,2)]
xdf
  month X
4   feb 1
5   feb 4
6   feb 9
7   mar 5
8   mar 8
9   mar 9

ddf2 = ddf[,c(1,3)]
ydf = ddf[ddf$month!=ddf2$month[is.na(ddf2[,2])], c(1,3)]
ydf
  month Y
1   jan 3
2   jan 4
3   jan 6
4   feb 8
5   feb 2
6   feb 4

ddf2 = ddf[,c(1,4)]
zdf = ddf[ddf$month!=ddf2$month[is.na(ddf2[,2])], c(1,4)]
zdf
  month Z
1   jan 3
2   jan 5
3   jan 2
7   mar 5
8   mar 4
9   mar 5
```